# 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch. (despite GO statements)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

### Background

To keep the views up to date, I want to keep each view as a `.sql` file within a `Views` folder. On the `Seed()` method, I am iterating through those files and executing the SQL.

I would like this SQL to drop and recreate the views.

### The Setup

A view file called `V_DW_PrepaymentReport.sql`:

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.views where name='V_DW_PrepaymentReport' and type='V')
DROP VIEW V_DW_PrepaymentReport

GO

create view V_DW_PrepaymentReport as

...(other SQL here to finish creating the view)
```

The seed method code (less relevant, but just FYI):

```
    private void RegenerateDatabaseViews(RsDatabase context)
    {

        var viewsDirectory = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Views";

        var allViewFiles = Directory.GetFiles(viewsDirectory, "*.sql").OrderBy(x=>x);

        if (!allViewFiles.Any()) { throw new Exception($"No view files found in {viewsDirectory}");}

        foreach (var viewFile in allViewFiles)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(viewFile));
        }
    }
```

### The Problem

When running `Update-Database`, upon hitting the `Seed` method and running the file, I see:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

### The Question

Why do I see this error, despite using a `GO` statement between batches? Is SQL server ignoring that keyword and considering the whole file to be one batch regardless?

Comment: Note: I know this might seem like a duplicate of other questions, so I want to say up front -- my question is specifically here because I have inserted a Go statement (per other answers) but I want to know if that's even being respected.

Comment: I would check to see what query is actually being sent to the server, SQL Profiler will help with that.

Comment: Does it work when you run it in SSMS? That drop syntax is not correct.

Comment: Edited to use a different drop syntax; was accidentally using SQL2016. Updated syntax & error message.

Comment: Side note: really not sure where the down-vote on this question comes from. I took a lot of time to format this question well I thought, so if someone has an issue with the question, I'd appreciate them specifying what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GO` commands are commands for [*client tools*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go), not for SQL Server. Each client tool will split the text into batches and submit each batch separately to the server.

Well, guess what - you're now taking SQL scripts and want the `GO` behaviour - so *you're* now implementing a client tool and it's up to *you* to implement that same behaviour.

Also, `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` doesn't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: Good call regarding drop syntax; will update it shortly.

Comment: Thank you -- this explains my fundamental misunderstanding. I was assuming that I was not operating as a client tool when I definitely was.